# Proving $x^5 - 7$ is irreducible/non-factorable.

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I know the polynomial must be irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ but I am not able to prove so using Eisenstein's. I tried $x = x \pm 1, 2, 3$ but was not able to find a prime number to satisfy Eisenstein's.

Comment: What's wrong with $p=7$? Without any substitutions whatsoever.

Comment: Ah, I forgot any number divides 0. Thank you